# Xamarin SqlConnection throwing error Input string was not in correct format

Tags: exception, mono, xamarin, sqlconnection

Im trying to connect my mobile to PC database using this code:

```
            string cString = @"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=myDB;server=192.168.1.11,1433\SqlExpress";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cString);
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name1 FROM Product", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        t.Text += rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("name1")) + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Unfortunately I'm getting error: "Input string was not in the correcr format", source: mscorlib.

I know that there's error in connectionString (throwin exception after connection.Open())

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens when you remove the ',1433' in the server address?

Comment: Error is "Access denied", source: System

Comment: Also, i've change connectionString to: "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=false;Initial Catalog=myDB;server=192.168.1.11\SqlExpress;User Id=login;Password=pass"; - still same error (Access denied)

Comment: It is generally a horrible idea to expose your DB server directly to the internet, which is what you are doing.  The preferred method is to use webservices to act as a broker between your external client (mobile app) and your database.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But anyway - why it doesn't work? Propably Ill use webservice, but atm I just need to check some functionality and be sure that I want to use Xamarin - that's why I need connection to DB.

Comment: can you log-in with those credentials from MS Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

your current  Culture is not in correct format

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        //Here you would read it from where ever.
        var userSelectedCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = userSelectedCulture;
    }
```